# More than 5 users can't be logged in at the same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have an asp.net web application, I have more than 15 users, my problem is that when the first 5 users login it works with no problem after that when another one wants to log in it just refresh the page and no errors appear so I have to restart the server then the user can log in.

```cs
if (IsValid)
{
    // Validate the user password
    var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    var signinManager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationSignInManager>();

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = signinManager.PasswordSignIn(Email.Text, Password.Text, RememberMe.Checked, shouldLockout: false);

    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            Cache.Remove(userName);
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
            break;

        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            Response.Redirect("/Account/Lockout");
            break;
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("/Account/TwoFactorAuthenticationSignIn?ReturnUrl={0}&RememberMe={1}",
                Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"],
                RememberMe.Checked),
                true);
            break;
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            FailureText.Text = "Invalid login attempt";
            ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I use SQL server

Comment: and which edition of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio version 15.0.18330.0